# right justify the text in input type file upload HTML

Tags: html, css

I face a strange problem in file upload input type format in HTML.
I wanted to `right justify` the text in the upload field,so i have tried using, 
 direction ="right" in  tag and also `dir="rtl"`

But this works fine IE, Mozilla but in case of Chrome since only the file name gets uploaded, its reading the file name in reverse order, for example,

1829487.htm is the actual file name, but in the upload box it displays as htm.1829487

Initially i thought since the path is not included so its reversing the complete name from right direction and displaying it.
In this process, i noticed that **if a file name contains at least one alphabet, it reads it properly and displays it with right justification**, for example,

18a294c87.htm is being uploaded as 18a294c87.htm

What is the reason behind this?

Thank you all so much in advance.

Comment: I always enjoy `rtl` stuff...

Comment: Why not try text-align: right; incase you need a right aligned name.?

Comment: I need to right align the uploaded file name, i tried using text align but it displays in default way.

Comment: any idea, why if an alphabet is there in the name, it reads correctly and not otherwise

Answer (score 0):

direction=right or dir=rtl reads from right to left, instead of the standard english way of reading from left to right, that's why it appears in reverse.

try using `style="text-align: right;"`

Comment: I tried using text align but that works only if input type is text, for input type as upload it displays in default way as left justified.